# Question about PrivateRoutes and to get navigated back to login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

Hi I need help getting my code to work so that when I try to log back in I won't be able to view the dashboard since I logged out. Right now its giving me a blank screen in my project and I think its because privateroute isn't a thing anymore? Not sure. This is my code in PrivateRoute.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth: { isAuthenticated, loading },
...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => !isAuthenticated && !loading ? (<Navigate to='/login' />) : (<Component {...props} />)} />
)


PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStatetoProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStatetoProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

This is the code for the app.js:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import Landing from './components/layout/Landing';
import Register from './components/auth/Register';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Alert from './components/layout/Alert';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard/Dashboard';
import PrivateRoute from './components/routing/PrivateRoute';
// Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import { loadUser } from './actions/auth';
import setAuthToken from './utils/setAuthToken';

import './App.css';

if (localStorage.token) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
}

const App = () => { 
  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);

return (
  <Provider store={store}>
  <Router>
    <Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
      <Route exact path='/' element={<Landing/>} />
      </Routes>
      <section className="container">
        <Alert />
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/Register' element={<Register/>} />
          <Route exact path='/Login' element={<Login/>} />
          <PrivateRoute exact path='/dashboard' element={Dashboard} />
        </Routes>
      </section>
    </Fragment>
  </Router>
  </Provider>
)};

export default App;
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

there is a recommended Protected Route implementation in the v6 react router docs you can follow.

[DOCS IMPLEMENTATION](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth)

**Your issue:**

```
<Route {...rest} render={props => !isAuthenticated && !loading ?
 (<Navigate to='/login' />) : (<Component {...props} />)} />
```

This Route is not up to date with v6, which I assume you are using, you need to update it.

Exact is also not supported anymore, there is no point in including it in your routes.

If you are not using v6 please update your post and include your react-router version.

Comment: I am using v6 I saw this on a udemy course but Im not sure why its not working? Its for DevConnector

Comment: The Udemy course is probably outdated and doesn't use react-router v6. You can either downgrade your version, or change all the Routes according to react-router-v6, which shouldn't be to hard. V5 > V6 was a pretty major update for react-router and it is not backwards compatible. If you don't want to put in the effort of rewriting your udemy code, you can just take the example implementatiton that I gave you from the docs.

Comment: could you help me switch it? ive been trying to but I keep getting errors

Comment: I don't want to downgrade